# inserting text with createTextNode

Tags: javascript, html

I'm obviously missing something **really** obvious with how `createTextNode` and `createElement` work - I've got [a very simple test](http://jsfiddle.net/857q6/1/) to display 'Hello World' in a div, but it doesn't display:

```
var sp = document.createElement('div');
var tx = document.createTextNode('hello world');
sp.appendChild(tx);
```

What stupid thing am I doing?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forgot append `sp`.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(sp)
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/857q6/3/)

Comment: Less of a case of 'forgot', more of a case of "I hadn't realised I needed to!"

Comment: document.body.appendChild(sp) is prolly better

Answer (score 3):

**TIP**

Cache the document, if you plan to add alot of elements.
and read about `document.createDocumentFragment();`;

All in one

```
var d=window.document;
d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('div')).appendChild(d.createTextNode('hey'))
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ba5VK/

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to append the div to the document.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing to append `sp` div to body
here an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/semir/DW6Dv/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sp = document.createElement('div');
var tx = document.createTextNode('hello world');

sp.appendChild(tx);
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(sp); //  add the div to the body of the document
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/857q6/4/)**